# Wiremock proxy unmatched requests

Tags: proxy, wiremock

I am investigating a possibility to proxy all the request that do not have mappings in Wiremock.
I found a mechanism to proxy requests creating a mapping for that.
But I want to have an ability to say: "Wiremock, if there is no mappings for that request, please proxy it to www.my-address.com" please.

Have anyone done this before?
Thanks!

I found a mechanism to proxy requests creating a mapping for that.
But I want to have an ability to say: "Wiremock, if there is no mappings for that request, please proxy it to www.my-address.com" please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can use the `priority` field](https://wiremock.org/docs/stubbing/#stub-priority) to set your ["catch-all" proxy](https://wiremock.org/docs/proxying/#proxy-stub-mappings) to a lower priority than all other mappings.

In the example below, there are two mappings. The first is matched on the url `/foo`. The second matches all other URLs. The first is checked *before* the second, because of the higher priority (lower number == higher priority). If a match is found, then WireMock stops checking. So, calls to `/foo` are checked and matched before they get the opportunity to be caught by the catch-all.

```js
{
  "mappings": [
    {
      "priority": 1,
      "request": {
        "url": "/foo"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200
      }
    },
    {
      "priority": 5,
      "request": {
        "urlPathPattern": ".*"
      },
      "response": {
        "proxyBaseUrl": "https://www.my-other-site.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Priority is what I was seeking!